# Build Docker and deploy to ECR using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I am very new to CDK and use dockers. For my application, for any code change I want the CDK pipeline to build the Docker and store it in ECR. I am seeing some examples but mostly found the one which have ECS task linked in it.

Is it possible to build docker and update ECR with most recent image through CDK pipeline ? If yes can you provide some example which does not involve ECS, just ECR and docker.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(https://github.com/cdklabs/cdk-ecr-deployment) this construct from the CDK labs should do just that, but its not super hard following the conventional approach: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-ecr-readme.html)